# Create Alias for localhost with Apache config file using PHP - XAMPP

Tags: php, apache

```
I installed XAMPP on my windows machine
I changed the DocumentRoot and Directory paths to
C:\dev\CustomCloud\prod
```

Since I did have XAMPP working on windows , I changed to point at code that i need to setup and modify.   Localhost I now see tons of 404 errors

This PHP code I am pointing at is trying to resolve an ALIAS of `localhost/matchmaking/`

Example:

```
C:\dev\CustomCloud\prod\assets
```

Is

```
http://localhost/matchmaking/assets/
```

How can I get the apache /xampp/ php to use an alias ?

This is easy with virtual directory with IIS for MS projects asp.net  but I was looking at this article   http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html

So would i do something like `Alias` or `ScriptAliasMatch` ?

```
 Alias "/docs" "/var/web" ... 
 ScriptAliasMatch "^/~([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/cgi-bin/(.+)"   "/home/$1/cgi-bin/$2"
```

Inside my config

```
  #DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
  #<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
  #"C:/dev/CustomCloud/prod"
  DocumentRoot "C:/dev/CustomCloud/prod"
  <Directory "C:/dev/CustomCloud/prod">
```

Comment: Please paste your configuration.

Comment: if possible you can make changes to windows host http://superuser.com/questions/249723/how-can-i-map-multiple-hostnames-to-localhost

Comment: @CalosKao    there is the only section i modified in apache config

Comment: @kumarsher45     no  - that is not it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this into configuration, and reload/restart service.

```
Alias "/matchmaking/assets" "C:\dev\CustomCloud\prod\assets"
```

Comment: Awesome!   So would I actually then not really want `assets` , but go a level up in the match ?   e.g.   "/matchmaking/"  "c:\dev\CustomCloud\prod"

Comment: @JeremyMiller Yes.